# Using short OR circuit inside strlen?

Tags: c, malloc

```
result.author = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(temp->author));

strcpy(result.author, temp->author);
```

I'm doing an RPC thing, but that is not the question about.
Here i want to allocate and copy string "UNKNOWN" if temp is NULL like the below code.

```
result.author = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(temp->author || "UNKNOWN"));

strcpy(result.author, temp->author || "UNKNOWN");
```

How can i accomplish that?

Comment: You need to add 1 to the string length, to allocate space for the null terminator. Other than that, this code should work.

Comment: I think `||` will evaluate to either `0` or `1`, so it will not do what you think it does.

Comment: Ternary operator or a simple if. What you are doing should not work because you are doing a OR operation. P__J__ answer sums it all

Comment: @Osiris Right. Thinking of just about every other modern language, which returns the first truthy value instead of just 0/1.

Comment: @Barmar Well AFAIK gcc would allow `strdup(temp->author?:"UNKNOWN");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result.author = malloc(strlen(temp->author ? temp.author : "UNKNOWN") + 1);

strcpy(result.author, temp->author ? temp.author : "UNKNOWN");
```

it is a shorthand of :

```
if(temp->author)
{
    result.author = malloc(strlen(temp->author) + 1);
    strcpy(result.author, temp->author);   
}
else
{
    result.author = malloc(strlen("UNKNOWN") + 1);
    strcpy(result.author, "UNKNOWN");   
}
```